# Woocommerce deletes all carts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to woocommerce, I'm having a problem my customers day to day add products to the cart, they finish the order in 5-6 days, but sometimes after 2 days the users are forced logeed out from WP and the carts are cleaned.

Or simply when they log out the cart is empty. I don't want this behavior. Is there some way to save the cart in the DB? or there is other way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this filters to adjust the period where products are in cart, remember that they are reduced from stock when added to cart.

```
add_filter('wc_session_expiring'   , 'my_wc_session_expiring') );

add_filter('wc_session_expiration' , 'my_wc_session_expiration') );
{

function my_wc_session_expiring($seconds) {
    return (60 * 60 * 24 * 8) - (60 * 60);
}
function my_wc_session_expiration($seconds) {
    return 60 * 60 * 24 * 8;
}
```

This should be adapted to your case.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried that, but the carts still are getting emptied